# Need help understanding joined reports

Tags: reporting, joined-reports

I was looking into joined reports and need some understanding of how the common fields are set.

For example 
I have a opportunity and Lead report types in my joined report. I also have one custom field in opportunity called lead source and i also have lead source in leads.

I dont see this field as a common field in the joined reports. How are the common fields determined?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please refer: [How Joined Reports Work](http://login.salesforce.com/help/doc/en/reports_joined_format_overview.htm)

A field is a common field if it’s shared by all report types or if all report types share a lookup relationship to the field. These fields appear in the Common Fields area in the Fields pane, and can be used to group report blocks.

Comment: if i am understanding this correct, then i need to have the field on opportunity for leadsource to be a lookup on leads to be able to show as a common field in joint report????

Comment: NO. The field needs to be present on both the objects. But the objects need related to each other via that field. So in case of Opportunities and Leads, Owner is the only field by which both can be related.